# Customizing Popups in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, style, popup

Is it possible to customize the shape of popups in OpenLayers? For example, I am creating a pop-up using the following approach:

```
var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                "popup",
                OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.toShortString()),
                null,
                '<div style="color:#FF0000">'+feature.data.Name + '</br><a href="http://test.url">test.url</a>' + '</div>',
                null,
                true
            );
```

This creates a popup with the following appearance:

[image]

Is it possible to change from the rounded corners and a curved 'connection' to a more square pop-up?

Comment: can you please show me your full framecloud code i actually want to know how to use framecloud to fetch data from WMS on click for a particular polygon and a particular column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

beside all answer you can make your popup as google map popup style. check out this [link](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/CloudAmber/Trunk/GooglePopups.htm) which will help you to make g-style popup...

popup script [codes](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/CloudAmber/Trunk/script/popup.js),

popup [images](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/CloudAmber/Trunk/script/img/corners/),

and so [css](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/CloudAmber/Trunk/map.css)...

[image: googlestyle]

i hope it helps you..

Answer (score 5):

In your library files, there is `img/cloud-popup-relative.png` file. You have to customize it in order to get infowindow you like

Comment: Thanks @Odoakr! Is there any advice on how to change it? At the moment I do see a png with the various pieces that create the pop-up, but I'm not sure what would happen if I changed the shape of each piece, or how the shape-boundary within the png is used.

Comment: To be honest, default cloud is fine for me. I didn't try to change it:) I googled for a while, but I didn't find any custom example...

Answer (score 5):

Just a note, from my recent task - to create custom popup in OpenLayers for WMSGetFeatureInfo.

What I do:

```
var highlightControl = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    url: 'url to wms', 
    infoFormat: 'text/html',
    queryVisible: true,
    eventListeners: {
        getfeatureinfo: function(event) { 
            this_is_popup_handler_function(event);
        }
    }
}); 

this_is_popup_handler_function(event) {
  alert(event.text);
}
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: forgot to mention, you might need to get the xy property from event. ;)

Comment: function this_is_popup_handler_function(event) {
  alert(event.text)
}

Answer (score 0):

To get xy try `event.xy`.

For example:

```
...
new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
             'chicken',
             map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
             ...
);
...
```